# Simplest example from Spring docs doesn't work. "Consider defining a bean of type 'xxxRepository' in your configuration."

Tags: java, spring

I'm getting really tired. The whole day I'm trying to do the simplest config of the application with DB, but nothing works, even when I copy tutorials 1:1.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

After copying all 3 classes (`MainController`, `UserRepository`, `User` + `pom.xml` from the provided package), change database config in `application.properties`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.example.testfield.MainController required a bean of type 'com.example.testfield.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.testfield.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

When I add `@EnableJpaRepositories` in `TestFieldApplication` and `@Repository` over `UserRepository` to force scan, then I'm getting:

```
Field userRepository in com.example.testfield.MainController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
```

When I tried to add manually `entityManager` in this way:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                         .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
                                         .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx")
                                         .username("xxx")
                                         .password("xxx")
                                         .build();
    }

    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(createJpaVendorAdapter());
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.TestField.entity");
        factory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

then I had a problem saying "No supported DataSource type found".

I tried everything - creating a new DB with new users, changing the version of every dependency, placing properties in `application.properties`... nothing works. I'm getting frustrated, because it's so basic stuff, and I tried a few tutorials, copying them, and nothing works, unbelievable!

Ps. I used the same url/user/password when connecting from the Intellij plugin to test the connection, and it worked.

Edit:
Add other classes

```
package com.example.testfield;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestField {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestField.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.testfield;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TestField</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` annotation scans packages only on its level and deeper. For example, if your main class in package `com.example.main` and your repository in package `com.example.repo`, repository won't be found.

Comment: You need mysql connector to your pom.xml `<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.27</version>
</dependency>`

And specify MySQL driver as `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Is your application a Spring Boot one? If yes, can you please add your main class, `MainController` and `UserRepository` code (including the package statements) and also your `pom.xml`? Thanks!

Comment: As geobreeze mentioned, In your manual attempt use this - com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver instead of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: I have all classes in the same package. Also I have MySQL driver specified, tried both `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, and tried `mysql-connector-java` version `8.0.27` as well as `5.x.x`.

Yes, it's Spring Boot, added other classes to the main post.

Also tried `java 1.8` & `11`

Comment: Have you tried removing `public DataSource getDataSource()` definition and using `spring.datasource.*` configuration properties?

Comment: @JoãoDias yes - when I don't put it at all in Config class, then I receive `.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set` exception.

When I leave method to just read properties from `application.properties` like this one:

`@Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                .build();
    }
`
then I'm getting `No supported DataSource type found`.

However I'm pretty sure that credentials and permissions are ok... I even made new DB on Postgres and same. :(

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't need to do any of that if you have the properties in your `application.properties`. Spring Boot autoconfiguration should kick in. The only bean you need to explicitly create is the one in `public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager`.

Comment: You are right, according to Spring docs I should not need Config class at all. No idea why it does not kick in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I was able to solve the problem.
Solution was to change return type of getDataSource method from:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()               
                                .url("xxx")                            
    (...)
                                .build();
    }
```

to:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("xxx")
        (...)
        return ds;
    }
```

A bit confusing, most of tutorials in the internet show the first way. Thanks to all who tried to help! :)